# count repeated values in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Example database:

```
userid / value
887 / x
887 / y 
2313 / x
2313 / s
123 / e
2313 / i
```

How Can i get the following response?

```
2313 / 3
887 / 2
123 / 1
```

Comment: It isn't obvious from your sample dataset whether you're trying to count values or distinct values, which have slightly different solutions.

Answer (score 4):

```
select userid, count(*)
from table_name
group by userid
```

edit: as anothershrubbery said, if you care about the order of the results then:

```
select userid, count(*) as frequency
from table_name
group by userid
order by frequency desc
```

Comment: Remember to add an alias to the `COUNT(*)` and `ORDER BY` said alias `DESC` to get the output as the OP wanted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` with aggregate function `count()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check the number of values per userid you can do it like this:

```
select userid, count(value) as total
from table_name
group by userid
order by total desc
```

If you are trying to check the *distinct* number of values per userid you can do it like this:

```
select userid, count(distinct value) as total
from table_name
group by userid
order by total desc
```